# Classically measuring position without disturbing the momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

Let's assume that the world is classical.
We have an electron somewhere in a room.
I am trying to understand how one can experimentally measure the position or the momentum of this electron without disturbing the other.

At the moment of measuring its position, it had some momentum which changes to a new value due to my interaction with it.

So classically how does one measure the position and momentum simultaneously to an arbitrary precison?

Comment: Might be important to mention its not the interaction that causes the uncertainty principle. By virtue of having a well defined state of position, a particle can't have a well defined momentum and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. This possibility of measuring it without actually measuring it can be done with the help of correlations. You fiddle with some other system and know about the first system and so HUP implies what u stated. But I am talking of a purely classical setting.  I am interested in knowing how would one measure the momentum and position without disturbing each other. Where you don't need any interaction such as using a ruler to measure the position like ACuriousMind mentioned does not measure both things simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Classically, you don't need to interact with a particle at all to measure its position. The particle has a well-defined position value at all times. You just place a ruler on the ground and look down on it from above to measure its position in one dimension, for example - this may be *practically* infeasible for something as small as an electron, but the distinction between classical and quantum measurements is not about practicality - the relevant difference is that a classical measurement does *not* require interaction that changes the state of the measured object. Likewise, you can measure the momentum/velocity just by making subsequent position measurements in this manner and timing the time between them.

Comment: If I just look at it with a scale how would I measure its momentum?